# else statement not getting executed?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I want to reload my page if the page is not fully loaded. I am using the below if-else loop. If part is working properly but the else part is not getting executed. I have no idea why is this happening???

Can someone help me to overcome this problem??

```
function loadCensusData(obj) {
  console.log(objXHR1.responseXML);
  var vals = objXHR1.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("val");
  var noOfCols = 4;
  var noOfRows = vals.length / noOfCols;
  var row = 0;
  while (row < noOfRows) {
    var Did = vals[row * noOfCols + 0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var DRevenue = vals[row * noOfCols + 2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var censusVariable = DRevenue;
    var div = Did;
    console.log(div);
    //console.log(censusVariable);
    if (censusVariable < censusMin) {
      censusMin = censusVariable;
    }
    if (censusVariable > censusMax) {
      censusMax = censusVariable;
    }
    map.data.getFeatureById(div).setProperty('census_variable', censusVariable);
    document.getElementById('census-min').textContent = censusMin.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById('census-max').textContent = censusMax.toLocaleString();
    row++;
  }
  if (document.readyState == 'interactive' || document.readyState == 'complete') {
    alert('Done');
  } else {
    alert('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');
    self.location.reload();
  }
}
```

- loadCensusData loads the data from my report.
- census_variable is used to apply color style

I have used the ready state conditions.

Can someone help me to overcome this problem??

Comment: Why would you expect that `else` condition to ever be true?

Comment: so, when is `loadCensusData` called? after document has loaded perhaps? if `document.getElementById('census-min').textContent` aren't giving you errors then, I guess document is at least interactive

Comment: @jaromanda-x Yes I get it now. Is there any other condition which we could to reload the page??